# How do you make a program with multiple "Pages"?

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, tabcontrol, wizard

How do you make something like the things where you install programs by clicking the "Next" button and it will show you like a `TextBox` instead of a `ComboBox` like on a new `Panel`?

Sort of like changing Tabs on a `TabControl` but without showing the tabs.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38719/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-wizard-in-c-sharp-2-0?rq=1

Comment: what have you tried so far? your question is not clear enough. Please correct otherwise it will be downvoted severly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably looking for Wizard. You may see

[Simple Wizard for Winforms - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/120607/Simple-Wizard-for-WinForms)

You may also take a look at [WinForms Wizard from DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Wizard/) but its not free.